# Find the lowest and second lowest values in an array of numbers

Tags: ruby, array

Trying to find way to do this with only one pass through the array, so I won't run a sort on it and take arr[0..1]. Not sure how to make it look better:

```
def LowestSecondLowest(arr)
  lowest,second_lowest = nil,nil

  arr.each do |n|

    if second_lowest.nil?
      second_lowest=n
    elsif lowest.nil?
      if n>second_lowest
        lowest=second_lowest
        second_lowest=n
      elsif n<second_lowest
        lowest=n
      end
    elsif n<lowest
      second_lowest=lowest
      lowest=n
    elsif n>lowest && n<second_lowest
      second_lowest=n
    end       
  end

  "#{lowest} #{second_lowest}"
end
```

Comment: It often results in simpler code to start with `lowest, second_lowest = VERY_LARGE_NUMBER, VERY_LARGE_NUMBER`

Comment: `Array#min` can return the two lowest values: [3,2,1].min(2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Array` lets you put repeated elements of same value, I believe that the two lowest elements in `[1, 2, 1]` are `[1, 1]`, not `[1, 2]`. This is the very same behavior one would face if sorting the array and getting the two first elements.
Also I believe that in `[1]` there is a lowest and no 2nd lowest (also, the very same behavior if sorting and getting the first two).

With this in mind, I changed your code to obey these premises (and make it a bit more readable if I may say). Take a look.

```
def two_lowest arr
  # if arr has no elements, there is no answer
  # If arr has only one element, this is the lowest
  if arr.size < 2 then
    return arr.first, nil
  end

  lowest, second_lowest = nil, nil

  arr.each do |n|
    if lowest.nil? or n < lowest
      # if we have no lowest or we found an element lower than current lowest,
      # update our lowest and 2nd lowest
      second_lowest = lowest
      lowest = n
    elsif second_lowest.nil? or n < second_lowest
      # if we have no 2nd lowest or we found an element between lowest and 2nd
      # lowest, update our 2nd lowest
      second_lowest = n
    end       
  end

  return lowest, second_lowest
end
```

If you want to test it

```
tests = [
  [],
  [1],
  [1, 1],
  [1 ,2],
  [1, 2, 1],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 1, 2, 3],
  [3, 2, 1, 1],
]

for test in tests
  puts "In #{test}:"
  puts "#{two_lowest test}"
  puts
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Gabriel. I understand the logic behind your revisions. I think my sloppiness came from not considering what would get caught in previous if/elsif statements, and therefore trying to accommodate unnecessary values in subsequent if/elsif statements

Comment: Treating corner cases before main iteration/recursion is a "trick" I usually do to simplify my code. So after all `if`s I can forget about corner cases and write just for the general case. I am glad I could help you, it is my first answer in CodeReview :-)

Comment: Would you mind elaborating for me what you mean? I'm still rather new to coding and general strategies like you mention here  are not familiar to me. Thanks!

Comment: This strategy is called "early exit". It is discussed [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement). I hope it helps!